# Can a runway turnpad be used as a runway holding position?

Tags: runways, ground-operations

[image]

Can a turnpad also be used as a runway holding position?

Comment: Since you're asking about regulations, please update your question to add which country and/or regulations you're interested in. This question [has already been asked](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/18930/62) for the US, for example.

Answer (score 4):

No, since you must have been cleared to enter the runway to be on the turn pad.  It is part of the runway.

From the point at which an aircraft is cleared to enter the runway, until it reports vacated or departs, the runway is occupied.

Comment: I'm not sure if ATC clearance would be the legal impediment; I've seen multiple a/c cleared onto the active in lots of small/crowded/strange airports (BVA,LTN) . I would think the lack of a holding marker on the ground would be a bigger issue, as I have effectivelly no reference of a line where my a/c will not inteferere with the one on arrival

Comment: @Radu094 Since you can't hold on an active runway, once cleared to enter, you must either vacate, take-off or abort. Regardless of how many aircraft, one or more means the runway is occupied.

Comment: well that's exactelly what (for instance) LTN does: with a clear to enter, backtrack, lineup and hold, then clear for intersection t/o for a second a/c behind us. Not sure of the legal implications, I was suprised originally, but now it seems common practice

Comment: @Radu094 Are you sure it's line up and hold, not line up and wait?  That sounds like a recipe for an accident.

Comment: from memory :" ..via Alpha clear to enter, backtrack, line-up and hold, there is departure ahead" ...I need to pay more attention to the radio...

Comment: @Radu094 - Here in the US, we can be given clearance from ATC to Line Up and Wait on the displaced threshold. It is quite common at one of our busier local airports while other aircraft are landing overhead. I would think that the term “line up and hold” would be avoided to avoid confusion. A better phrase would be to “Hold short runway xx. You are number x behind the [plane model]”. This particular airport has a pretty long displaced threshold where more than one aircraft can line up and wait.

Comment: @Simon - I occasionally fly into an airport (KRYW) that allows the turn pad to be used as a holding point. There are no taxiways to the AER and no displaced threshold. You have to backtaxi to the AER and immediately perform a rolling 180 on the runway surface in order to takeoff. If you want to stop at the AER to perform a run up, or use the turn pad to change directions, you have to completely exit the runway onto the turn pad. Once you are on the turn pad, re-entry onto the runway is not allowed without performing full runway hold short procedures.

Comment: @DeanF. my understanding of a "displaced threshold" means that there's a line painted on the runway and you're not allowed to land before crossing that line. Are you saying that your airport will put one or more aircraft _on_ the runway prior to that line then have another aircraft land directly overhead? If so, that sounds incredibly dangerous and a violation of all sorts of rules.

Comment: @FreeMan - Interesting point. According to FAA JO 7110.65, some airfields can do it and some airfields can not. Then, in combination with FAA JO 7210.3BB, there appears to be time of day and weather restrictions as well. I wonder if having a nearly 1000 foot displaced threshold and taxi way all the way past the end of the displaced threshold play a factor in it as well.

Comment: @FreeMan - I suppose the thought process would be that controlling that space of the runway is less dangerous than if the displaced threshold were actually marked as a taxiway extension. It would also be less dangerous than some smaller airfields that have other vehicles access the AER when there is not a displaced threshold. I’ve seen automobile driveways as well as fence lines mere feet from the AER. Then there is the occasional industrial lawn mowing tractor. At least they usually carry airband radios and are in touch with the tower. Tower usually notifies landing traffic of their presence.

Answer (score 1):

Not withstanding Simon's answer, the answer would be that it depends on the runway. The runway in the picture above has a displaced threshold and what appears to be a hold short (runway exit) line separating the runway from the turn pad.

The hold short line would indicate that the turn pad can be used as a place to hold while waiting for clearance for departure. With or without the displaced threshold, ATC could clear you to backtaxi onto the runway in order to reach the turn pad. Once there, you would begin holding short once the entire plane is beyond the hold short (runway exit) line. Holding there would not be an impediment to either arriving nor departing aircraft.

For departing aircraft, ATC could use the turn pad as extra room when having multiple aircraft performing Line Up And Wait maneuvers, preparing for departure. A scenario with a displaced threshold would put aircraft on the turn pad far away from the start of the Landing Distance Available.

Without a hold short line, ATC would not be able to hold the aircraft on the turn pad. Although, they could still issue a LUAW instruction by having the aircraft back taxi on the runway. It would probably then be up to the pilots discretion on where to perform a 180 turn around and where to hold as long as it is before the AER demarcating the beginning of the LDA.